# Spaces in Android with Swype at Cordova-application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an really simple Cordova-application. When I publish this for Android with an Input-field, there will be no spaces when I use Swype. Sample code:

```
<input type="text" name="test">
```

We use Cordova 3.0.0 (CLI) on several Android-devices.

Does anyone know an solution for this?

Comment: Problem not clear. Would you please elaborate it?

Comment: As I said, when I use Swype on my Android with my Cordova-based app and use an input field, I write "Hello World" with Swype, there comes: "HelloWorld". Thats with every sentence written with Swype..